# iOS locationmanager didChangeAuthorizationStatus not called from kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied to kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized status

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

The didChangeAuthorizationStatus is called kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied state in setting app > Privacy > Location Services > My app > Never in background mode.
But After changing 'Always', didChangeAuthorizationStatus is not called.
Also not called when 'Location Services' off.

I inserted NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription at my Info.plist and set location update background mode.

My code,

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {       
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        _locationManager.delegate = self;
        _locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

        if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:)]) {
            NSLog(@"setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates");
            _locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
        }

        [self requestAuthorization];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    NSLog(@"CLAuthorizationStatus: %d", status);
}
```

Sorry my english.

Answer (score 7):

I was having this exact problem and it turned out I was creating my `CLLocationManager` and calling

`-requestWhenInUseAuthorization`

on a background thread. I called those methods on the **main thread** and got the expected results (`-locationManager:didChangedAithorizationStatus:` was called after I tapped "Don't Allow" or "Allow")

Comment: Finally a solution! And as @LOP_Luke alluded to I found I had to do both the CLLocationManager initialization and the permission request on the main thread, not just the permission request

Answer (score 1):

To summarize Newtz comment....

Swift 3

```
var locationManager:CLLocationManager? = .none
```

...

```
// Set up your location manager as desired
DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
      self.locationManager?.delegate = self
      self.locationManager?.activityType = self.activityType
      self.locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = self.desiredAccuracy
      self.locationManager?.distanceFilter = self.distanceFilter
      self.locationManager?.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
      self.locationManager?.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
  }
```

...

```
// Authorize
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // If you're not in the background you like need requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
}
```